# Scope is not being shared in my AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple markup :

```
<div ng-app="superApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <superhero> HOVER ME </superhero> {{a}}
</div>
```

The following  code changes `{{a}}` to  `444`  :

```
var app = angular
      .module('superApp', [])
      .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope)
      {
          $scope.a = 444;
      }])
```

Result :

```
HOVER ME 444
```

Now I add  code for the Directive :

```
app.directive('superhero', [
        function ()
        {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                controller: function ($scope)
                {
                    $scope.a = 555;
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs)
                {
                    element.bind("mouseenter", function ()
                    {
                        scope.a = 999;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
]);
```

The result is :

```
HOVER ME 555
```

Which means it is the same scope as the controller sees.

But if I hover the label , the `{{a}}` doesn't changed  to `999`

**Question**

Why doesn't the `{{a}}` changed to `999` ? isn't it the same scope ?

Also -  Batarang shows  2  scopes both ng-app ???

[image]

[*jsbin*](http://jsbin.com/gihofehogo/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `mouseover` event is out of the scope of angular. It is a jQuery event.

There are two solutions the better one would be to make use of core directives like `ng-mouseover` in your directives template if it uses one. Or in jQueries event handler use `$scope.$apply()`.

```
element.bind("mouseenter", function ()
{
    scope.$apply(function (){
        scope.a = 999;
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/buzuveludu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks. How many scopes are here ? I mean why does Batarang show 2 ?

Comment: My understanding is one scope shared between the two directives but i could be wrong on that. I know providing `scope: {}` in your directive definition creates a second isolated scope for your directive. Your edit looks like its defining your app in its entirety twice for some reason. Never heard of `Batarang ` but i wouldn't have expected that behavior to be caused by a simple directive like the one your using. It could also be possible the directive has its own scope but it is linked to the parents but i couldn't say with certainty.

Comment: There is no `ng-hover` directive. What you are thinking of is `ng-mouseover`. Please edit this post

Comment: @RichardHamilton My mistake, very tired.

Comment: @RichardHamilton why do i see 2 scopes ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, there is a root scope ($id = 1) and the scope of the controller ($id = 2)